# Android Activities for Chat Application: Which flags or lauchmodes for Contact List (Roster) and Chat Conversation?

Tags: android, android-intent, chat

I'm making a chat app using aSmack and I'm using activity A as my Login, B as my Contact List and C as the conversation activity(where you chat). So basically is:

> A → B → C

On activity B I've set android:launchMode ="singleTask" so it dosen't create a new instance everytime I press the back button on activity C and so far it works.

My goal is to create new instances of C and at the same time not destroy those instances when I go back to B. Like normal chats do. So it will be for example:

> A → B → C1
>
> A → C1 → B → C2

And be able to call back C1 and not create a new instance. For example:

> A → C2 → B → C1

I've try using different Intent flags and Launchmodes and so far only failed. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can simply save the state of your app to some sort of database then load it again. i.e; saving current conversation and activity.